# What is this flat pin battery connector on my quadrocopter called?

Tags: identification, quad-copter

**Has somebody seen this type of connector before and can tell me what it is called?**

It has flat pins, a 2 mm pitch, and "wings" on the side to prevent reversing it. Copious amounts of searching the internet only told my that the Syma X5C obviously features the same type of connector but with only two pins, but not the name of this type of connector.

---

A bit of context: I've got a new quadrocopter from UDI R/C, Model "Discovery FPV" or "U818FPV". I'd like to upgrade the battery, to a larger one, but that is difficult to do without knowing what the connector on the drone is called. Of course I could replace the connectors on the drone and the original battery and the charger, but I'd rather not.

[image: Connector]
[image: Connector]

Comment: Sorry, but the photo quality is too poor to see the battery itself. Have you tried using the model number to find a users manual/guide which should have a parts list? Your asking us to do this for you.

Comment: @Sparky256 The question is about the type of the connector shown, not about the battery or the copter. That's why the photos show only the connector. I don't want anyone to search datasheets or manuals, I just want to know if somebody has seen this type of connector before and knows what it is called. If you don't know it, that's okay. I have a user guide and parts list, but it just says "battery" and does not name the connector type. Printed on it is "Li-Po Battery 402545-350mAh 3.7Vx2", but googling that just yields places to buy it, not the connector type.

Answer (score 4):

It is known by a few different names:

- Walkera plug
- Losi connector or Micro Losi
- Micro-T or Micro-T/B/DT

[image]

You can buy the 4 pin version [here](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Losi-Micro-Walkera-4-Pin-Connector-plug-Male-Female-Crimps-x-50-Sets/32611034655.html?spm=2114.01010208.3.1.BOguWf&ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_8,searchweb201602_4_10057_10056_10055_10049_10017_405_404_10059_407_10058_10040,searchweb201603_4&btsid=086d0b8e-b0a1-4c12-b8e7-45e376edf47f).

The housings and crimp contacts are also manufactured by Molex. The part numbers are:

- Female housing: 51005
- Female crimp contacts: 50013
- Male housing: 51006
- Male crimp contacts: 50012

Comment: Could you add any reference?

Comment: @BenceKaulics sorry, what do you mean by references?

Comment: Thanks a lot! When searching for losi/walkera, I also found this thread, which gives a Molex part number: http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2011982 The Male housing is part 51006 and the male crimp contacts are 50012. Female is 51005 with 50013 connectors: http://www.molex.com/molex/products/datasheet.jsp?part=active/0510060200_CRIMP_HOUSINGS.xml

Comment: I meant a link or something to show where you have found the connector. You have added it right away.